# How to open emacs in new window after using ssh login

Tags: emacs, ssh, bash

When I open my terminal and type "emacs", a new emacs window opens. But after using ssh to log in to another host, typing "emacs" creates an emacs buffer inside the terminal.

Is there any way I can specify when using ssh that I want windows to be opened outside of the terminal? Perhaps inserting something into my .bashrc?

NOTE: I already tried using "ssh -Y" instead of "ssh". It didn't work.

EDIT: I don't know why it didn't work before, but now both "ssh -Y" and "ssh -X" solve my problem.

Comment: you need to have installed X client on your remote server, where you want to run emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Emacs was not compiled to use a windowing system, you will not be able to do this. What does `C-u M-x emacs-version` output? Typically (certainly with recent versions of Emacs) that will indicate the presence of `X` support.

If it's been compiled with X, then one of the `-X` or `-Y` ssh arguments (taking appropriate note of the warnings) is indeed how this is done, so you'd presumably have to dig a little into those to figure out what might be going awry.

(Failing that, you can of course use your local GUI Emacs to access the remote files over ssh via TRAMP.)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to export the X windows.

Try:

```
ssh -X user@machine
```